# Force requirement check in "Get Windows 10"

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

How can I force the "Get Windows 10" application in Windows 7 to check if the computer meets the requirements for Windows 10 after I've changed some components?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Windows 10 directly with a Microsoft media creation tool, as is specified [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/970090/101336).

Interesting, that when you open [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) from Windows(I don't see it from my host OSX system browser) hopefully you will see notice on the page:

> IMPORTANT: To upgrade for free, select Upgrade this PC now in the
>   tool. You should NOT be asked for a product key during the upgrade
>   process.

So this is somewhat official way to upgrade.

Comment: I can confirm this. The tool won't really download anything unless the system meets the specifications.

Comment: I have just successfully upgraded Windows 8.1 instance inside Virtual Box to Windows 10 this way. I had a problem that according to compatibility report Virtual Box graphics adapter was not compatible. So I uninstalled the driver in Device manager(not sure if this step is required when you use Media creation tool), and instead of waiting another month hoping for the best upgraded via this tool. I that this don't think that this policy when you can't troubleshoot, but instead have to wait Microsoft for month to run the report is good at all.

Answer (score 0):

The "Get Windows 10" application automatically checks for compatibility after each reboot/startup. When incompatibilities are found, the Get Windows 10 app will alert you. There's not really any way to force a re-check, except maybe restarting your computer. If you are still concerned about your computers compatibility, You can follow these steps to double-check.

1. Right click the Get Windows 10 Icon, and select "Check your upgrade status"
2. Click the side menu button (Three lines on top of each other, top right)
3. Click "Check your PC" in the side menu
4. Any incompatibilities will be listed here

Comment: Isn't double check the same as force re check?

Comment: As I said in my answer, the get windows 10 app automatically checks for incompatibilities on each startup.

Comment: That is not correct - it runs compat check once per month.

Comment: proof: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/compatibility-report-windows-10  How often does the report run?
The report runs automatically about once a month. If you installed apps or devices recently, or made changes to your PC, the report might not reflect these changes.