# Windows 10 - Force hardware compatibility check

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, compatibility

I am still struggling with the Windows 10 hardware compatibility check. I had a GeForce 7900 which was incompatible, so I bought a new card which is supported. But the "Get Windows 10 app" still complains about the previous card. In other words, the compatibility check isn't ran again (yet).

I tried to force the Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser (as administrator)

```
C:\Windows\system32>schtasks.exe /Run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experi
ence\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"
SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Exp
erience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser".
```

I waited for an hour, but when I click on the "View report" button it shows that the last run of Compatibility Appraiser was 8/17/2015. So forcing the compatibility check seems to result in nothing.

Some other supposed solution was to delete the downloaded files in "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download". and then run (as administrator) "C:\Windows\system32>wuauclt /updatenow"

What is the best way forward? I don't mind to start over again, but I don't know if that is possible (like, uninstalling the Get Windows 10 app and delete all the local data it stored so far, and reapply for the free upgrade).

PS: I have Windows 7 Ultimate installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a solution, i will avoid the *Get Windows 10* app.

The **Plan B** i propose is *Media Creation Tool* , a free tool from Microsoft that allows you to force upgrade any PC to Windows 10 for free (from genuine Win 7 or 8.1).

```
 Steps:
```

> 1.[Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) the tool and run it with admin rights.

2.After temporary installation files are unpacked, select *Upgrade this PC now* and click Next
[image]

> 3.The rest of the installation is automatic. Windows 10 will be downloaded and installed automatically.

Comment: nr1 snaks, thanks for the help! worked like a charm.

Comment: When did windows become more of a pain than linux? If only my parents were more computer literate...

Answer (score 3):

From my own experience, it seems that the **Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser** scheduled task does nothing if it has already been run in the last 24 hours. To force the  task to actually perform the check again, you have to convince it that more than 24 hours have passed by changing the windows date & time settings to a future date (e.g. tomorrow). If you then run the task again, wait roughly 15 minutes* and then open the upgrade dialog from the system tray, you should see that the data has now been updated. Don't forget to set the clock back to the correct date and time afterwards.

If you need to re-run the check, you'll need to make sure the clock is at least 24 hours ahead of when it thinks it last ran, e.g. if you advanced the clock to tomorrow for your first attempt, you'll need to advance the clock another 24 hours from there for your second attempt.

*The actual time may vary - for best results, open **Control Panel\Administrative Tools\Task Scheduler**, expand **Task Scheduler Library\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience** and check the status of the **Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser** task.